# How to add events to built-in calendar?

Tags: application-development, 19.04, evolution, calendar

I am looking for way to add events to [this calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JQ5d.png).

I know that I can use third-party applications to do it from GUI (or sync it with online service like Google) but I am specifically interested on how it can be done programmatically (from my own app for example).

So far I've been hitting my head against the wall trying to google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Evolution data server](https://developer.gnome.org/eds/stable/) (EDS) is the backend application that your software should interface with.